# How do I make a specific property of an object immutable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

if I have an object like

```
let person = {
       firstName: 'Krishna',
       lastName: 'Jai',
       age: 12
}
person.firstName = 'Kumar';
console.log(person);

//output
Object { firstname: 'Kumar', lastName: 'Jai', age: 12 }
```

But I should not let any user to change the firstName of person. how to make firstName immutable so that its value cannot be overriden?

Comment: Well actually all of your object's properties already have immutable values by definition because they are of `String` type. The right phrase should be read only and non-configurable property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options, but probably the simplest is to make a read-only, non-configurable property:

```
let person = {
    lastName: 'Jai',
    age: 12
};
Object.defineProperty(person, "firstName", {
    value: "Krishna",
    enumerable: true
});
```

The flags `writable` and `configurable` both default to `false` when, as above, you're defining a new property. (You don't *have* to make it enumerable, as far as that goes, but...)

Example:

```js
let person = {
    lastName: 'Jai',
    age: 12
};
Object.defineProperty(person, "firstName", {
    value: "Krishna",
    enumerable: true
});
console.log("before: ", person.firstName);
person.firstName = "Mohinder";
console.log("after setting in loose mode:", person.firstName);
function foo() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("trying to set in strict mode:");
    person.firstName = "Mohinder"; // Error
}
foo();
```

Or if you want to apply the change after the fact, you need to specify the flags:

```
let person = {
    firstName: "Krishna",
    lastName: 'Jai',
    age: 12
};
Object.defineProperty(person, "firstName", {
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
});
```

Example:

```js
let person = {
    firstName: "Krishna",
    lastName: 'Jai',
    age: 12
};
Object.defineProperty(person, "firstName", {
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
});
console.log("before: ", person.firstName);
person.firstName = "Mohinder";
console.log("after setting in loose mode:", person.firstName);
function foo() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("trying to set in strict mode:");
    person.firstName = "Mohinder"; // Error
}
foo();
```

Comment: _The flags writable and configurable both default to false_ - yes, but only if the property being defined for the first time, correct? If it has already existed, the descriptor will be merged

Comment: @Maximus: [Well what do you know...](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor)

Comment: This is neatly explained. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, _Well what do you know..._ - didn't understand what you meant

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, can you clarify? Here is what MDN says: _If the old descriptor had its configurable attribute set to false (the property is said to be “non-configurable”), then no attribute besides writable can be changed_. I'm wondering how it can be changed...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, based on [this article](http://webreflection.blogspot.nl/2011/10/do-you-really-know-objectdefineproperty.html) it seems that `configurable:false` has no bearing on `writable`, but `writable` itself can only be changed from `true` to `false`, not the other way around. Check the [plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/bLpwemof/1/)

Comment: @Maximus: I meant "You're right, I didn't know that." :-) Re configurable: The point is that a read-only property that anyone can reconfigure to be writable isn't really all that read-only, which is why I *also* made it non-configurable.

Comment: @Maximus: The thing with [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLpwemof/1/) is you're not setting both `writable` and `configurable` to `false`, so your subsequent change to `value` is allowed -- the property isn't read-only. When both are false, though, you can no longer change its value (even by reconfiguration): https://jsfiddle.net/bLpwemof/3/ Details of why in the [spec section linked above](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, _which is why I also made it non-configurable_ yes, that's what I didn't specify initially in my answer. _The thing with your fiddle..._ - correct, because I wanted to show that setting `configurable:false` doesn't prevent modification of `writable` and `value` properties

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, exactly, it prevents changing `writable` **only if** `writable:false` and `configurable:false` **by itself** doesn't prevent modification. That was my point. I think we understand each other now :)

Comment: @Maximus: I think so, thanks. TIL that if `configurable` is `false`, I can still change `writable` from `true` to `false`, which is...just wrong. :-) (But clearly stated in Step 8.a.i in the spec. Bizarre.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, how's your Angular2 learning going? I started writing in depth articles on angular on medium, for example [this one](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02#.xwa5pq2dt). You might want to follow me :)

Answer (score 12):

If you already **have a property in place**, you can modify it's descriptor's  `writable` property to `false` like that:

```
Object.defineProperty(person, 'firstName', {
      writable: false,
      configurable: false
});
```

`configurable: false` should be specified to prevent future modifications of the `firstName` property, e.g. changing `writable` back to `true`.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Writable_attribute) about property descriptors.

If you're defining a property that **didn't exist** before, then all descriptor properties are defaulted to `false` and the only things you need to specify are `value` and `enumerable`:

```
Object.defineProperty(person, "firstName", {
    value: "Krishna",
    enumerable: true
});
```

Comment: Not quite sure I know what you mean by that, but applying the above to the OP's object definitely leaves `firstName` open to re-configuring (and therefore becoming writable again): https://jsfiddle.net/11fcmftd/

Comment: ...whereas if you add `configurable: false`, it protects it: https://jsfiddle.net/11fcmftd/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [getter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and omit the setter.

```js
let person = {
       get firstName() { return 'Krishna'; },
       lastName: 'Jai',
       age: 12
    };

person.firstName = 'Kumar';
console.log(person);
```

Comment: I prefer this method personally.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Why? Why require a function call on every access to the property when there's no reason to do so?

Comment: Because... neatness. :P

Comment: In JS, this is not the right way to do this job since i can easily override the above code by adding a single line like `Object.defineProperty(person, "firstName", {get : function(){ return "Nina Scholz"}});console.log(person.firstName)`