# Javascript object variables constant

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to make some or all of objects variables constant? I tried with const keyword but got error.

```
const testVar = { const x : 777 , y : 888 };
```

Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: **No**. what is your *actual goal* in this?

Comment: Have a look at [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) or [Object.preventExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions)

Comment: Maybe you want [Object freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Comment: why don't you simply do: `const x = 777; const obj = {x, y:888}` ?

Comment: [How do I make a specific property of an object immutable in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42853592/104380)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a specific property of an object immutable in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853592/how-do-i-make-a-specific-property-of-an-object-immutable-in-javascript)

Comment: @vsync Umm... That doesn't work.

Comment: @D.Pardal It depends [on how you read the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936154/javascript-object-variables-constant#comment111296355_62936190).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could make the properties of an object immutable. Couple of them are mentioned below.

#### Using Object.freeze() function

`Object.freeze()` function prevents object properties from being changed. You won't be able to change existing properties of an object and you also won't be able to add new properties.

```js
const testVar = { x : 777 , y : 888 };

Object.freeze(testVar);

testVar.x = 2;  

console.log(testVar);
```

#### Using Object.defineProperties() function

Properties defined on an object using `Object.defineProperties()` function are by default, not writable, not configurable and not enumerable.

```js
const testVar = {};

Object.defineProperties(testVar, {
   x: { value: 777, enumerable: true },
   y: { value: 123, enumerable: true }
});

testVar.x = 1;

console.log(testVar);
```

For details of above mentioned functions:

- [Object.defineProperties()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)
- [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Comment: `freeze` ? what does it has to do with this question?

Comment: OP wants to prevent any property of `testVar` object from being modified.

Comment: Why do you think that? I don't see him asking this. You are assuming this. I assume he simply wants a reference for that number, as a variable.

Comment: @vsync "_Is it possible to make some or all of objects variables constant?_" reads to me as "How can I make some or all object properties immutable" (or at least un-reassignable).

Comment: to me it doesn't read that. `const` decelerations have been replacing `var` decelerations in recent years and it is possible OP simply wants to access that specific key. If he wanted to make a specific key immutable he could have simply asked or googled it, instead.. I'm not 100% sure, but i'm guessing

Comment: @vsync: Dude.., you both might be wrong.. surely the OP can speak up for him/herself. No use in making a fuss about it. If you think your answer/guess is more suitable just post it as an answer.

Comment: @JavaScript - for now OP seems to not be able to speak or simply doesn't care enough to check this post 100-times-a-minute like I would have done if this was my question :)

Comment: @vsync: Many posters here are just playing "hit and run" anyway, nothing new. But you trying to assume for the OP what is correct and what not, if you are uncertain yourself, does not make much sense to me. I can relate to it, really can.. but it is ultimately useless. Most people just use `let`and `const` because it is trendy without really needing it or knowing the differences in all those declaration types.

Comment: _Is it possible to make some or all of objects variables constant?_ i am not sure why everyone got confused. The fact that OP put `const` keyword before an object's property only means one thing and that is OP is trying to make object property immutable.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I think freeze() is just perfect for my problem as I don't want the object to be modified later on

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) which will allow you to set:

- the `writeable` property descriptor to `false` to disallow assignment to the properties
- the `configurable` property descriptor to `false` to disallow removing the properties

```js
const testVar = { y : 888 };

Object.defineProperty(testVar, "x", { 
  writeable: false,
  configurable: false,
  enumerable: true, //to show up when printing the object
  value: 777
});

console.log(testVar);

testVar.x = 100;
testVar.y = 200;
console.log(testVar);

delete testVar.x;
delete testVar.y;
console.log(testVar);
```

And here is an example of setting multiple properties:

```js
const testVar = { y : 888 };

Object.defineProperties(testVar, {
  x: { 
    writeable: false,
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    value: 777
  },
  z: { 
    writeable: false,
    configurable: true, // allow deleting
    enumerable: true,
    value: 999
  }
});

console.log(testVar);

testVar.x = 100;
testVar.y = 200;
testVar.z = 300;
console.log(testVar);

delete testVar.x;
delete testVar.y;
delete testVar.z;
console.log(testVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `const` keyword does not make a "deep structure" constant. In your case it will only prevent a complete reassignment.

The `Object.freeze()` that other answers are talking about will not work for deep structure either (or it would be called `deepFreeze()` ).

Try this :

```
const obj = { name: "Joe", job: { title: "Worker" } }
// Let's freeze it
Object.freeze(obj)

// This time let's change the job title
obj.job.title = "Manager"

console.log(obj) // {name: "Joe", job: {title: "Manager"}}
```

Using `let` gives you the block scoping that you need and is much more clear to understand to going the `const` route.

You will need to look into libraries that will proxy the var for you to make it immutable (eg. `immutable.js` https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/).

Answer (score -1):

Try this -
const testVar = { x : 777 , y : 888 };

Object.freeze(testVar);

Hope this will help.